# Is using 'var' to declare variables optional?

Tags: javascript

Is "var" optional?

```
myObj = 1;
```

same as ?

```
var myObj = 1;
```

I found they both work from my test, I assume `var` is optional. Is that right?

Comment: "Optional" is perhaps an unfortunate choice of words, as `var` is optional in the sense that an assignment statement can be successfully interpreted with or without it, but not optional in the case where you want to explicitly declare a variable in local scope.

Comment: Check out this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GWr6Z/2/

Comment: One other difference nobody mentioned: `console.out(var myObj=1)` doesn't work, but `console.out(myObj=1)` outputs 1. See my answer (currently at the very bottom)

Answer (score 596, accepted):

They mean different things.
If you use `var` the variable is declared within the scope you are in (e.g. of the function). If you don't use `var`, the variable bubbles up through the layers of scope until it encounters a variable by the given name or the global object (window, if you are doing it in the browser), where it then attaches. It is then *very similar* to a global variable. However, it can still be deleted with `delete` (most likely by someone else's code who also failed to use `var`). If you use `var` in the global scope, the variable is *truly global* and cannot be deleted.

This is, in my opinion, one of the most dangerous issues with javascript, and should be deprecated, or at least raise warnings over warnings. The reason is, it's easy to forget `var` and have by accident a common variable name bound to the global object. This produces weird and difficult to debug behavior.

Comment: You can create a variable inside a method without using `var`. That doesn't make it global, IE does that often, how can that be dangerous?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: Wrong.  It does.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: Yes, it does make it a global variable.

Comment: @codemeit : javascript is full of pitfalls like this, but all in all it's a beautiful and very pleasant language. Don't hate it. Just know the pitfalls and leave them out of your code.

Comment: Automatic global variables are removed from ECMAScript 5 strict mode, which is basically an implicit deprecation. Hopefully implementations will give a warning if you forget `var` in non-strict mode.

Comment: Actually no, assigning to a variable without using `var` does not make it *global*. It causes JS to traverse up the scope chain, eventually ending up at the global object if the variable was not used anywhere before. If the variable *was* declared using `var` somewhere before global, that's the scope that will be used. It's also an integral part of how JS works and what makes it really powerful, so I wouldn't describe it as a "pitfall".

Comment: @deceze: traversing up the scope chain is a good thing, but adding it to the global scope if it doesn't find anything is a pitfall.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman If you were right, that would mean that different browsers interpreted the absence of var differently. How can you then NOT think that omitting var is dangerous? If your claim were right, you would be even more wrong.

Comment: Delete is actually a little funky across browsers (IE and safari specifically do things differently).  It's *not* for variables, it's for properties.  var foo = 1 is a declaration, which sets it's dont_delete flag to true.  bar = 1 is a blind assignment, which does not set it's dont_delete flag.  bar = 1 will create a global ONLY if it there is nothing named bar in the scope chain between where it's assigned and the global object.

Comment: It says here on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FValues%2C_variables%2C_and_literals) that it always declares global variables if `var` is not used and **also**  JS will generate strict warning. However, [it](http://jsfiddle.net/2nSHs/) doesn't.

Comment: Simple, just don't forget to use var.  That's like forgetting a $ in php.  Or do like I do, and use an IDE that color codes those non-var variables differently.  I like this feature, it makes things in js easier and cleaner.

Comment: @Sid It won't generate a warning if you're not in strict mode.

Comment: When it bubbles up through the scope until it finds a similarly named variable, is it bubbling up through the call stack?  I.e. in one file, I have `function1`, which declared and used a variable. At some point, some of the functionality was scoped out into a helper function, `function2`. The use of the variable was moved, but the declaration was still in `function1`. So `function1` and `function2` are declared in the same file scope, and `function1` calls `function2`. Does this un-declared var in `function2` bubble up to `function1`'s scope, or does it go to file scope and up from there?

Comment: I just noticed this due to recently updating both node and VSCode, not sure which led to this behavior, but now unused variables are greyed out. So, this variable I'm talking about is greyed out in `function1`, and used without declaration in `function2`. But from the sounds of it, the `function1` scope declaration should catch the `function2`'s use, so it seems misleadingly greyed out in my editor.

Comment: When it comes to JS, `console.log()` is your friend. Or, some type of debugger tools in your text editor. It's critical to write just a little bit of code at a time and keep testing it in some fashion.

Answer (score 143):

This is one of the tricky parts of Javascript, but also one of its core features. A variable declared with `var` "begins its life" right where you declare it. If you leave out the `var`, it's like you're talking about a variable that you have used before.

```
var foo = 'first time use';
foo = 'second time use';
```

With regards to scope, it is ***not*** true that variables automatically become global. Rather, Javascript will traverse up the scope chain to see if you have used the variable before. If it finds an instance of a variable of the same name used before, it'll use that and whatever scope it was declared in. If it doesn't encounter the variable anywhere it'll eventually hit the global object (`window` in a browser) and will attach the variable to it.

```
var foo = "I'm global";
var bar = "So am I";

function () {
    var foo = "I'm local, the previous 'foo' didn't notice a thing";
    var baz = "I'm local, too";

    function () {
        var foo = "I'm even more local, all three 'foos' have different values";
        baz = "I just changed 'baz' one scope higher, but it's still not global";
        bar = "I just changed the global 'bar' variable";
        xyz = "I just created a new global variable";
    }
}
```

This behavior is really powerful when used with nested functions and callbacks. Learning about what `functions` are and how scope works is the most important thing in Javascript.

Comment: This is really the best answer because knowing the actual behavior of the scope chain is key to understanding how functional Javascript works -- even if you don't prefer to code in a functional style it is very nice to know considering how many commonly used libraries *do* use a functional style.

Comment: Isn't `var foo = 1` moved to the top of the current function scope, and not right where you declare it?
`foo = 100;` `bar = 200;` `(function fooBarDeluxeEdition() {` `bar = 300;` `//var bar = 400; // try uncommenting this for fun! :)` `}());` `document.write(bar);`

Comment: @carl The statement itself is not moved to the top, no. Essentially, a `var` statement reserves the variable name within the current scope, and it will start out with an `undefined` value. The assignment of the initial value will only happen exactly where you wrote `var .. = ..`.

Comment: @deceze Yeah, I was a bit quick off the mark. My point was that the answer (tho good otherwise) states that the variable begins its life at the `var` statement. But in reality, if I'm not mistaken, all `var` statements are scanned before the function scope is executed so all the variables are "born" at the start of the scope even though they are assigned at the `var`. It might be contrived, but my example shows a scenario where you could be scratching your head for a while (especially if you are a lover of multi-page functions).

Comment: @carl Well, fair enough, sort of. It *"begins its life in the scope"*. Does that fit better? :)

Comment: Actually your example is very misleading. `xyz` will never become a global variable because you never call the internal function and there is no way to call it from outside.

Comment: This is the best answer, that wiped away in 2 lines my longest confusion. Thank you @deceze. I appreciate it.

Comment: @FLAW “wbu”? Anyway, yes, hoisting exists. But this here is more about nested scopes and in which scope the variable “begins its life”. Hoisting is another separate concept to consider, but out of scope for this answer.

Answer (score 82):

Nope, they are not equivalent.

With `myObj = 1;` you are using a global variable.

The latter declaration create a variable local to the scope you are using.

Try the following code to understand the differences:

```
external = 5;
function firsttry() {
  var external = 6;
  alert("first Try: " + external);
}

function secondtry() {
  external = 7;
  alert("second Try: " + external);
}

alert(external); // Prints 5
firsttry(); // Prints 6
alert(external); // Prints 5
secondtry(); // Prints 7
alert(external); // Prints 7
```

The second function alters the value of the global variable "external", but the first function doesn't.

Comment: Be careful saying "you are using a global variable".  "myObj = 1;" refers to a variable in an outer scope, which may not be global.  Your example, however, does reference (and potentially implicitly declares) a variable in the global scope.

Answer (score 23):

There's a bit more to it than just local vs global.  Global variables created with `var` are different than those created without.  Consider this:

```
var foo = 1; // declared properly
bar = 2; // implied global
window.baz = 3; // global via window object
```

Based on the answers so far, these global variables, `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are all equivalent.  This is **not** the case.  Global variables made with `var` are (correctly) assigned the internal `[[DontDelete]]` property, such that they cannot be deleted.

```
delete foo; // false
delete bar; // true
delete baz; // true

foo; // 1
bar; // ReferenceError
baz; // ReferenceError
```

This is why you should **always** use `var`, even for global variables.

Comment: I think your insight deserves more exposure so I edited the chosen answer to include this information.

Answer (score 17):

There's so much confusion around this subject, and none of the existing answers cover everything clearly and directly.  Here are some examples with comments inline.

```
//this is a declaration
var foo;

//this is an assignment
bar = 3;

//this is a declaration and an assignment
var dual = 5;
```

A declaration sets a DontDelete flag.  An assignment does not.

A declaration ties that variable to the current scope.

A variable assigned but not declared will look for a scope to attach itself to.  That means it will traverse up the food-chain of scope until a variable with the same name is found.  If none is found, it will be attached to the top-level scope (which is commonly referred to as global).

```
function example(){
  //is a member of the scope defined by the function example
  var foo;

  //this function is also part of the scope of the function example
  var bar = function(){
     foo = 12; // traverses scope and assigns example.foo to 12
  }
}

function something_different(){
     foo = 15; // traverses scope and assigns global.foo to 15
}
```

For a very clear description of what is happening, this [analysis of the delete function](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) covers variable instantiation and assignment extensively.

Comment: "food-chain of scope" => "scope chain"

Comment: I found this to be the most concise explanation and demonstration of the behavior. I know this is old, but it's still valid and I think it could be improved by calling each function followed by a statement of `foo` to show that it causes an error in the first case and has magically been added to the global scope in the second case. If you prefer, I can edit it myself.

Answer (score 16):

`var` is optional. `var` puts a variable in local scope. If a variable is defined without `var`, it is in global scope <strike>and not deletable</strike>.

#### edit

I thought that the non-deletable part was true at some point in time with a certain environment. I must have dreamed it.

Comment: Short, but not correct. If it is "defined" as you say without var, you **can** delete it. But not using var does not always declare a new variable, it may reference one in an outer scope.

Answer (score 9):

[They are not the same.](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3)

Undeclared variable (without `var`) are treated as properties of the global object.  (Usually the `window` object, unless you're in a `with` block)

Variables declared with `var` are normal local variables, and are not visible outside the function they're declared in.  (Note that Javascript does not have block scope)

**Update: ECMAScript 2015**

`let` was introduced in ECMAScript 2015 to **have block scope**.

Answer (score 9):

Check out this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GWr6Z/2/

```
function doMe(){

a = "123"; // will be global
var b = "321"; // local to doMe
alert("a:"+a+"  --  b:"+b);

b = "something else"; // still local (not global)
alert("a:"+a+"  --  b:"+b);

};


doMe()
alert("a:"+a+"  --  b:"+b); // `b` will not be defined, check console.log
```

Comment: Some one with sense very undervoted my +1

Comment: simple explanation and thanks for Fiddle

Answer (score 6):

The var keyword in Javascript is there for a purpose.

If you declare a variable without the var keyword, like this:

```
myVar = 100;
```

It becomes a global variable that can be accessed from any part of your script. If you did not do it intentionally or are not aware of it, it can cause you pain if you re-use the variable name at another place in your javascript.

If you declare the variable with the var keyword, like this:

```
var myVar = 100;
```

It is local to the scope ({] - braces, function, file, depending on where you placed it).

This a safer way to treat variables. So unless you are doing it on purpose try to declare variable with the var keyword and not without.

Comment: +1 for "t can cause you pain if you re-use the variable name"

Comment: Not braces.  JavaScript variables are not block-scoped but function-scoped.  A var anywhere in a function body is exactly equivalent to a var at the top of the function body.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this question asked at StackOverflow today:

[Simple Javascript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485032/simple-javascript-question/2485053)

A good test and a **practical example** is what happens in the above scenario...
The developer used the name of the JavaScript function in one of his variables.

**What's the problem with the code?**
The code only works the first time the user clicks the button.

**What's the solution?**
Add the `var` keyword before the variable name.

Answer (score 4):

*Var* doesn't let you, the programmer, declare a variable because Javascript doesn't have variables. Javascript has objects. *Var* declares a name to an undefined object, explicitly. Assignment assigns a name as a handle to an object that has been given a value.

Using *var* tells the Javacript interpreter two things:

1. **not to use** *delegation* reverse traversal look up value for the name, instead use this one
2. **not to delete** the name

Omission of *var* tells the Javacript interpreter to use the first-found previous instance of an object with the same name.

Var as a keyword arose from a poor decision by the language designer much in the same way that Javascript as a name arose from a poor decision.

ps. Study the code examples above.

Answer (score 1):

Everything about scope aside, they can be used differently.

```
console.out(var myObj=1);
//SyntaxError: Unexpected token var
console.out(myObj=1);
//1
```

Something something statement vs expression

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not "required", but it might as well be as it can cause major issues down the line if you don't. Not defining a variable with var put that variable inside the scope of the part of the code it's in. If you don't then it isn't contained in that scope and can overwrite previously defined variables with the same name that are outside the scope of the function you are in.

Answer (score -2):

I just found the answer from a forum referred by one of my colleague. If you declare a variable outside a function, it's always global. No matter if you use var keyword or not. But, if you declare the variable inside a function, it has a big difference. Inside a function, if you declare the variable using var keyword, it will be local, but if you declare the variable without var keyword, it will be global. It can overwrite your previously declared variables. - See more at: http://forum.webdeveloperszone.com/question/what-is-the-difference-between-using-var-keyword-or-not-using-var-during-variable-declaration/#sthash.xNnLrwc3.dpuf

Comment: Look at the previous answers please, you are not adding anything.