# jQuery difference between "var name" and "$name"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have read some articles about the titled cited but not found anything from which i could understood. Can anyone please tell me what is the purpose of "$varName"? why we use "$" sign before a variable?

Comment: $ sign just helps you to notice that the variable contains jQuery object. There's nothing else about it other than coding style preference. This question was asked many times here though, it's weird if you couldn't find it. For example, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329185/in-jquery-what-is-the-difference-between-using-the-dollar-sign-vs-var

Comment: There is no difference, that's just a convention to use $ as prefix for varibale name refering for example to a jq object

Comment: It's purely a naming convention. The `$` prefix means this variable holds a jQuery object.

Comment: It's a common convention that variables prefixed with `$` are denoting a jQuery context (as opposed to a native `HTMLElement`). So you can further call jQuery methods on it (like `$myDiv.show()` for example).