# unable to get input value from <input>

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I can't seem to get the input value for "name", I have tried using .value in JS but when I run the code I get undefined.

HTML code

```
<div class="col-1">
<label for="fname">Name</label>
</div>
<div class="col-2">
<input type="text" id="fname"  placeholder="Enter name"  required>
</div>

<div class="col-3">
<button  onClick="gather()" id="submitButton">submit</button>
</div
```

> 

JS code

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submitButton");
submit.addEventListener("click",gather);

function gather(){
  name = document.getElementById("fname");
  message = "Thank you for subscribing "+name.value+ "!";
  alert(message);
}
```

Comment: Did you try giving the input an empty value parameter? `value=""`

Comment: weird, your code looks correct. what does it say when you log just the input element (name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `var` for create variable and all work.

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("submitButton");
submit.addEventListener("click",gather);
function gather(){
  var name = document.getElementById("fname");
  var message = "Thank you for subscribing "+name.value+ "!";
  alert(message);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1">
  <label for="fname">Name</label>
</div>
<div class="col-2">
  <input type="text" id="fname"  placeholder="Enter name"  required>
</div>
<div class="col-3">
  <button  onClick="gather()" id="submitButton">submit</button>
</div>
```

I suggest you to see this post:

[Is var necessary when declaring Javascript variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892696/is-var-necessary-when-declaring-javascript-variables/3892715)

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do .value in the same line and get the value of the element

```
name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
console.log(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put all your codes into window.onload. This method running your code when all elements in page loaded. And this will solve your problem.

```
window.onload = () => {
//some js codes
}
```