# onclick modifier function referencing variable instead of using variable value (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, variables, onclick

*(Edit: Someone asked for where `trueName` is defined in relation to the loop, so I included it in the code sample. `relPath` is defined in the function parameter)*

I have a forEach loop that is meant to clone a template and set an onclick function to open a link for each clone. From the code sample below, you can see that I have 2 variables - `relPath` and `trueName` - that are supposed to form part of the parameter passed to the function:

```js
function showDirectoryItems(relPath, data){
    Object.keys(data).forEach((item)=>{
        nameSplit = item.split(">>");
        trueName = nameSplit[0];
        ...
        if (data[item]=="file"){
            clone.getElementById("name").onclick = function() {downloadFile(relPath+'/'+trueName)};
        ...
```

So in theory, one of the clones would have an onclick function of (for example) `downloadFile('files/test1.txt')`, another would have `downloadFile('files/test2.mp3')`, etc.

However, when I run the code, the onclick functions in all of the clones seemed to link to the same path of the last item.
I checked the code and realised that the onclick functions used variable references instead of an absolute value (i.e., instead of something like `'files'+'/'+'aaa.txt'`, it was `relPath+'/'+trueName`):

[image: Image showing the onclick function of an element referencing the relPath and trueName variables instead of an absolute value]

As such, how do I set the onclick function to take in the ***absolute value*** of these variables during the forEach loop, ***instead of a variable reference***?

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance, I've edited my question to include more code, including where trueName and relPath are defined. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix the problem in the end by changing the line where `trueName` is defined:

```js
trueName = nameSplit[0]
```

and adding `var` in front of `trueName` to declare it as a variable:

```js
var trueName = nameSplit[0]
```

What I'm guessing is causing the issue, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3892715/) to another question, is that because I did not put `var` when declaring the variable, the code treated `trueName` as a implicit global, thus causing the onclick function to reference the variable name instead of getting the variable's value directly.

Answer (score 0):

## Hey your question may like this:

HTML:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach((e) => {
  name123 = e.innerText;
  e.onclick = function () {
    alert(name123);
  };
});
```

## Click any of them will show 9, the last element;

[image: etc]

## Solution:

Move the [nameSplit, trueName] to onClick scope.

## In my example like:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach((e) => {
  e.onclick = function () {
   name123 = e.innerText;
   alert(name123);
  };
});
```

[image: etc]