# JavaScript form works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome

I'm just finishing off an assignment which required me to build a little form that totals order details etc. It works perfectly fine in Chrome, but I ran a test in Firefox (as the assessors will be using that) and it fails to work at all. Any tips or solutions as to why would be appreciated. Thanks

JavaScript

```
function list(theform){

  var mem = theform.elements["mem"].value;
  var cov = theform.elements["cover"].value;
  var cha = theform.elements["charger"].value;
  var scr = theform.elements["screen"].value;
  var del = theform.elements["delivery"].value;
  var qty = theform.elements["qty"].value;


  acc = (parseInt(mem) + parseInt(cov) + parseInt(cha) + parseFloat(scr) + parseInt(del)) * qty;

  total.value = "$" + Math.round(acc*100)/100;
  return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="accform" onsubmit="return list(this)">

        <label class="third column" for="memory">Memory</label>
        <label class="third column" for="case">Case</label>
        <label class="third column" for="memory">Charger</label>

        <select  class="third column" id="mem" name="mem">
          <option value="0">2GB : No charge</option>
          <option value="5">4GB : $5.00</option>
          <option value="12">8GB : $12.00</option>
          <option value="24">16GB : $24.00</option>
        </select>

        <select  class="third column" id="cover" name="cover">
          <option value="0">No case </option>
          <option value="4">Leather case : $4.00 </option>
          <option value="4">Silicon case : $4.00 </option>
        </select>

        <select  class="third column" id="charger" name="charger">
          <option value="0">No charger </option>
          <option value="5">Car charger : $5.00 </option>
          <option value="6">Car charger holder : $6.00 </option>
        </select> 

        <label class="third column" for="memory">Screen protector</label>
        <label class="third column" for="case">Shipping</label>
        <div class="full column"></div>

        <select  class="third column" id="screen" name="screen">
          <option value="0">None</option>
          <option value="0.99">x1 : $0.99</option>
          <option value="1.79">x2 : $1.79</option>
          <option value="2.39">x3 : $2.39</option>
          <option value="3.40">x5 : $3.40 </option>
        </select>
        <select  class="third column" id="delivery" name="delivery">
          <option value="0">Normal shipping : No charge </option>
          <option value="35">Expedited Delivery (Fedox) : $35.00</option>
        </select>
        <div class="full column">
        </div>

        <label class="third column" for="qty">Quantity</label>
        <label class="third column" for="total">Total</label>
        <div class="full column">
        </div>

        <div class="third column">
        <input  id="qty"/>
      </div>
        <input class="third column "id="total"/>

        <button class="submit">Calculate</button>
        <div class="full column">
        </div>

      </form>
```

Comment: Not the answer, but a good note, make sure your <form> and </form> tags are not in different elements (i.e. a <td> and after </table>) otherwise, it may not work in FF or IE (but will in Chrome >.>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works fine on my Firefox, even though it was emitting an warning in the console:

> Element referenced by ID/NAME in the global scope. Use W3C standard
>   document.getElementById() instead.

That was because `total` wasn't defined inside your function, try:

```
document.getElementById('total').value = "$" + Math.round(acc*100)/100;
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curyn/)** <-- Tested on Nightly 15a

Check if it helps and whether the fiddle works or not in your Firefox.

Also, as noted by @dibs, you can define `acc` by adding `var` in front of it:

```
var acc = (parseInt(mem) + parseInt(cov) + parseInt(cha) + parseFloat(scr) + parseInt(del)) * qty;
```

But that is unlikely to give you any trouble, besides maybe accidentally creating a global-scope variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try linting your script at [jslint.com](http://jslint.com) to see what errors you have in there.

```
'acc' was used before it was defined.
```

Comment: In JavaScript you don't have to define a variable before use.

Comment: @Derek is right, jslint is a little too demanding in the validations sometimes.

Comment: Not declaring a variable automatically makes it global. So it's good practice to always declare so as to avoid issues with scope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/javascript-is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional