# Jquery not fetching 'h1' from text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code

```
success: function(data) {
 title = $(data).find('h1').text();
alert(data);
alert(title);

}
```

Now data is showing all the html with h1 tags but title is showing null

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Comment: It's actually showing `null`? I would think it would show an empty string if no matches were found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.find()` method looks for descendant elements, so if your h1 element is at the "top" level it won't be found. Try `.filter()` instead:

```
title = $(data).filter('h1').text();
```

> *"Basically i want to grab the h1 and put in variable and then put the remaining html in data variable"*

Given a `data` parameter that is a string something like this:

```
"<h1>My heading</h1><p>This is a test</p><p>This <span>is another</span> test.</p>"
```

You can do this:

```
var $data = $(data),
    $title = $data.filter("h1"),
    title = $title.text();

$data = $data.not($title);
```

The above results in two jQuery objects: `$title`, which contains the h1 element, and `$data`, which contains the rest. From there you can use `$title.text()` to get the actual text of the h1.

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yyKCW/

If you mean that you want the "remaining html" as a *string* then you can do the following after setting `$data` as above:

```
var restAsString = $("<div></div>").append($data).html();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yyKCW/1/

Answer (score 2):

If your data consists of something like:

```
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>content</p>
```

Then you need to wrap it before performing your queries:

```
var title = $('<div/>').html(data).find('h1').text();
alert(title);
```

Comment: thanks buddy that worked. i was not wrapping it. one thing more what is the diff between `title=xxx` and `var title = xxxx`

Comment: @user1544681 glad it helped! Here is a good answer to your `var` question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2485895/187954

Comment: @user1544681 feel free to accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem!

Comment: IS there any way to remove that from the html and store that in $data

Comment: @user1544681 sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Basically i want to grab the h1 and put in variable and then put the remaining html in `data` variable without div tags

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14604/discussion-between-michael-robinson-and-user1544681)