# jquery Multiple alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i count element once?
Right now, evert time, when i click #totalItems, alert is rised as many times, as many element are in #photoId ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        photoId = $('.photoId');
        totalItems = $('#totalItems');

        $(photoId).on('click', function(){
              //alert ($(this).html()); 
              $(this).clone().appendTo(totalItems);

              $('#count').on('click', function(e){
              sizes = (totalItems.children().size()); 
              alert (sizes);
              });

              $('#count').off('click', function(e){
              sizes = (totalItems.children().size()); 
              alert (sizes);
             });       
        });          
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please share the relevant part of the HTML as well.

Comment: Check this out for [declare variable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2485451/2097224)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line :

```
$(photoId).on('click', function(){
```

By :

```
photoId.on('click', function(){
```

Comment: No, i have created loop.  This : $('#count').on('click', function(e){ should be on its own code, not in  $(photoId).on('click', function(){. That was soure of bug. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching `$('#count').on('click', function() { ...` handler on every click on `.photoId`. Make sure it is only done once from within the document's `ready` event.

In case your `#count` is actually inside the DOM being cloned, you need to

1. get rid of ID and replace it with class.
2. bind event to the top level container with CSS filter

I.e. something like this:

```
$("#totalItems").on("click", ".count", function() { ...
```