# ajax success(data) to variable += data

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is my code:

```
 var myVariable = "<div>";

 for (i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
 myVariable += '<div class="user' + i + '">'; 

 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "uziv=" + i,
      url: "../php/ajax_objednavky.php",
      success: function(data){
      //alert(data);  work well
      //$('#content').html(data); work well
      myVariable += data; //doesn't work
      }              
    });

 myVariable += '</div>';

 } 

 myVariable += "</div>";
 $('#myDiv').html(myVariable);
```

PHP file looks like

```
<? echo "data from mysql"; ?>
```

I can view the data using alert, but how can I add data to a variable?

Comment: what is `myVariable`?  Might be `scoping` problem

Comment: can u post the content of data and what you got when run your program in myVariable

Comment: You did declare myVariable as var myVariable?

Comment: @DannyThunder that could not be an issue.  check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/javascript-is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional

Comment: Post all code, this quiestion doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes i declare as var, myVariable.innerHTML doesn't work

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Edited.

It is probably because the ajax request take some time to finnish. By the time the first result gets back, the JS is allready finnished.

This code might be improved, but I hope you get what I mean.

```
var myVariable = "<div>";

 for (i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
 myVariable += '<div class="user' + i + '">'; 

 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "uziv=" + i,
      url: "../php/ajax_objednavky.php",
      success: function(data){
        myVariable += data; //doesn't work
        myVariable += '</div>';

        if(i == 4){
          myVariable += "</div>";
          $('#myDiv').html(myVariable);
        }
      }              
    });
 }
```

Instead of sending every `i`, you could send all of them in on ajax-request as json and get all result back in one request. This will need some reconstruction of your service, but It might be the better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised by your post :

```
data: "ter="+ objednavky + "&uziv=" + uzivatel,
```

I always used
    data: { ter: objednavky, uziv: uzivatel }

Easier to read, IMHO.

then, What do you mean by "doesnt work ?"

try this :

```
 myVariable += data;
 alert("foo");
```

Do you see the foo alert ? (I would expect that you messed up with "" and it is not PRINTED on the div, but it "works"). Exemple : ""

Comment: yes, I see foo alert. I can see in alert(data) but, I can't add data to myVariable.

Comment: Assuming you posted the code you try to execute (no typo in div), try :  var txt = new String(data) ; myVariable += txt;

Answer (score -1):

I guess that is what you need because there is no need to concatenate the data with myVaraible.

**Updates:**

The reason, the ajax **`data`** is returning an **`object`**. So concatenating will be not a good one. So I guess you might have data.something. Check this in such a way.

In-case if it is a object, then the *concatenation output* will be

```
<div>[object Object]
```

Comment: myVariable is simple variable

Comment: @user2887469 Agree@iJay  , it won't work.  Can you provide more details.  What are you actually trying?  Do you want the data to shown inside the div (myVariable)

Comment: @user2887469 The reason, the ajax `data` is returning the object.  So concatenating will be not a good one.  So I guess you might have `data.something`.  Check this in such a way.  If it is a string it would have worked http://jsfiddle.net/VAyNX/

Comment: @user2887469 what is your `data` have?