# Javascript variable not displaying in simple HTML script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a simple html page that counts up indefinitely. But for some reason my second variable is not being displayed. The second variable is an embedded javascript timer As you can see the first variable is displayed, but not the second. Apologies, I'm a beginner.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44188718/time.html

```
<script>
var test;
test = 123;
</script>

<script>document.write(test)</script>


<script>
var time;
time = 0;

function startTimer()
{
    window.setTimeout(add(), 60 *  1000);
}

add()
{
    var += 1;
}
</script>

<script>document.write(time)</script>
```

Comment: You should put your code in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please click "edit" and add the relevant code directly to your question.

Comment: `var += 1;` should probably be `test += 1;`. But also, I don't see any code that will update the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your middle script element contains several errors.

This line:

```
window.setTimeout(add(), 60 *  1000);
```

should be:

```
window.setInterval(add, 60 * 1000);
```

`setTimeout()` calls a function exactly once. `setInterval()` calls a function repeatedly. Also note that I've removed the `()` after `add` - with parentheses it calls the function immediately and passes its result to `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`, but you want to pass the function itself so just use the function name with no parentheses. (And the `window.` part is optional).

Then this line:

```
add()
```

should be:

```
function add()
```

And this:

```
    var += 1;
```

should be:

```
    time += 1;
    // OR
    test += 1;
```

(I'm not sure which variable you intend to increment.)

Also you never call the `startTimer()` function.

Finally, in your `add()` function you'd need to actually output the value. `document.write()` is almost never a good idea, so I'd suggest creating an element on your page to hold the number and updating its content:

```
<div id="timer"></div>

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time; // or = test; (whichever var you want)
```

Demo of all of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3XMk/

Or the same effect with simplified code: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3XMk/1/

Comment: Thanks, very well documented and easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

There are several misconsceptions in your code, so I will try to go through them.

1. You have to specify the `function` keyword when you define a function. In your case:

   ```
   add(){ ... }
   ```

   Should be:

   ```
   function add() { ... }
   ```

   Then you can safely call it from your `setTimeout` code.
2. Using the keyword `var` you are basically telling that you are about to define a variable [for the current scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/javascript-is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional). First of all, since the current scope is `window` anyways ([the global scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope)), you don't need to add `var`. Secondly, you have to use the variable name when you change it, or add to it. In your case:

   ```
   var += 1
   ```

   Should be:

   time += 1
3. Functions get called once, when you call them. In your case, `document.write(time)` will get called once when the document is parsed, and hence will write `1` in your document. You have to call the `write` method inside your add function, to have numbers show up at every interval. So:

   ```
   function add(){
       time += 1;
       document.write(time);
   }
   ```
4. [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) calls the specified callback function once, after the time is passed, I believe you are looking for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval). You can use it like so:
       function startTimer(){
           window.setInterval(add, 60 * 1000);
       }
   But don't forget to call your function, in order for the timer to start.

Here is an example of your code (it works every second instead):

<kbd>[Working fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ufijuFE/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong with your code.

I believe what you are trying to do is this:

```
<script>
    var time = 0;
    window.setInterval(function(){
    document.write(time);
    time++;
    }, 60*1000);
</script>
```

See a working demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8MVFB/

Just click "Run".

Comment: document.write is not allowed in jsFiddle so even if he click "Run" it won't run.

Comment: JSFiddle blocks the document.write I did try the code to no avail, but I don't see any glaring issues with it.

Comment: @HaukurHaf - In wich browser? (I tried Chrome, FF, Opera and IE10)

Comment: I'm using Chrome 30 / Win 8.1 - Note the interval, it will not do anything until a minute has passed.

Comment: My bad, didn't see that 1 minute delay in `setInterval()`. Sorry for my mistake.