# Return doesn't work javascript

Tags: javascript, return, innerhtml

my return var doesn't want to return. What do i do wrong? i get this error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: totaal1 is not defined .

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
$("totaalprijs").innerHTML = totaal1 + totaal2;
$("gerecht1").onchange = function () {
    var aantal = $("gerecht1").value;
    var prijs = 7.9;
    console.log(aantal);
    totaal1 = aantal * prijs;
    return totaal1;
}
$("gerecht2").onchange = function () {
    var aantal = $("gerecht2").value;
    var prijs = 9.9;
    console.log(aantal);
    totaal2 = aantal * prijs;
    return totaal2;
}
```

Comment: Use variable declaration like: "var totaal1" instead of just "totaal1"

Comment: Where did you define `totaal1`?

Comment: Similar problem explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/javascript-is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional

Comment: Error tells everything. Uncaught ReferenceError: **totaal1 is not defined .** Define it before you use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On this line:

```
$("totaalprijs").innerHTML = totaal1 + totaal2;
```

...you're trying to use a variable, `totaal1`, that isn't declared anywhere. Hence the `ReferenceError`, if you try to read the value of a variable that isn't declared, it causes that error.

To fix it, declare the variable (and ideally assign it a meaningful value), or don't use it in that calculation. (And then do the same for `totaal2`, because it doesn't seem to be declared anywhere, either.)

Now, the fun thing here is that if the `change` event fires on `gerecht1` and `gerecht2`, `totaal1` and `totaal2` will get *implicitly* created as global variables, via [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). But because those change handlers aren't attached until after the code causing the problem, they never get attached, because of the error.

FWIW, I think you probably wanted something like this:

```
var totaal1 = 0, totaal2 = 0;
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};
var updateTotaalPrijs = function() {
  $("totaalprijs").innerHTML = totaal1 + totaal2;
};
updateTotaalPrijs();
$("gerecht1").onchange = function () {
    var aantal = parseFloat($("gerecht1").value); // Or possibly `parseInt(..., 10)`
    var prijs = 7.9;
    console.log(aantal);
    totaal1 = aantal * prijs;
    updateTotaalPrijs();
};
$("gerecht2").onchange = function () {
    var aantal = parseFloat($("gerecht2").value); // Or possibly `parseInt(..., 10)` 
    var prijs = 9.9;
    console.log(aantal);
    totaal2 = aantal * prijs;
    updateTotaalPrijs();
};
```

And also FWIW, I would suggest using function declarations most of the time, and wrapping everything to avoid creating globals:

```
(function() {
  var totaal1 = 0, totaal2 = 0;

  function $(id) {
      return document.getElementById(id);
  }

  function updateTotaalPrijs() {
    $("totaalprijs").innerHTML = totaal1 + totaal2;
  }

  updateTotaalPrijs();

  $("gerecht1").onchange = function () {
      var aantal = parseFloat($("gerecht1").value); // Or possibly `parseInt(..., 10)`
      var prijs = 7.9;
      console.log(aantal);
      totaal1 = aantal * prijs;
      updateTotaalPrijs();
  };
  $("gerecht2").onchange = function () {
      var aantal = parseFloat($("gerecht2").value); // Or possibly `parseInt(..., 10)` 
      var prijs = 9.9;
      console.log(aantal);
      totaal2 = aantal * prijs;
      updateTotaalPrijs();
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare totaal1 and totaal2 variable so try below code:

```
 var totaal1=0,totaal2=0;
 var $ = function (id) 
 {
     return document.getElementById(id);
 }
 $("totaalprijs").innerHTML = totaal1 + totaal2;
 $("gerecht1").onchange = function () 
 {
    var aantal = $("gerecht1").value;
    var prijs = 7.9;
    console.log(aantal);
    totaal1 = aantal * prijs;
    return totaal1;
  }
 $("gerecht2").onchange = function () 
 {
    var aantal = $("gerecht2").value;
    var prijs = 9.9;
    console.log(aantal);
    totaal2 = aantal * prijs;
    return totaal2;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In line

```
$("totaalprijs").innerHTML = totaal1 + totaal2;
```

you're trying to access global variables `totaal1` and `totaal2`, which are local to event handlers functions. The handler return value is purposed for internal DOM event processing and not working this way.

What you want is to update `#totaalprijs`, when `gerecht1` and `gerecht2` are updated, so you better to create common `onchange` handler, which will do all calculations

```
var $ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

// Common change handler
function calc(e) {
   var aantal1 = $("gerecht1").value,
       aantal2 = $("gerecht2").value,
       prijs1 = 7.9,
       prijs2 = 9.9,
       total = aantal1 * prijs1 + aantal2 * prijs2;
   $("totaalprijs").innerHTML = total;
}
$("gerecht1").onchange = calc;
$("gerecht2").onchange = calc;
calc(); // Call on load, to calculate on initial values
```