# Global object declared in function not accessible by other functions

Tags: javascript, canvas, scope, global

In this code `window.onload` is used to delay the execution of the script to prevent references to the canvas occurring before the canvas is loaded. Withing `start()` the code `map.fillStyle="CCFFEE` runs as expected. I did not use `var` when declaring the `map` variable so as to make global to be referenced by other functions such as `draw()` and `start()`. However, for some reason `start()` accepts the variable as is, and uses it as expected, drawing the rectangle (in this case the background) to the screen while `draw()` throws an error when trying to use the variable. Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined`. This also occurs in the `update()` function as well as in the global scope outside of any functions. This has been tested with `console.log("Map: " + map);`. I hope that was concise enough for you to help.

```
window.onload=function() {
    init();
}

var fps = 30;
var now;
var then = Date.now();
var interval = 1000/fps;
var delta;

function Player(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}

function Collider(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('map');
    map = canvas.getContext('2d');
    start();
}

function start() {
    //Player Object
    player1 = new Player(gameMap.w / 3, (gameMap.h / 7) * 5, 30, 30);

    //Player Collider Object
    p1Collider = new Collider(player1.x - 15, player1.y - 5, player1.w + 30, player1.h + 130);

    //fillStyle and fillRect work here
    map.fillStyle="#CCFFEE";
    map.fillRect(0, 0, 1280,800);
}

function update(){
    //Error happens here too
}

function draw() {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    now = Date.now();
    delta = now - then

    if (delta > interval) {
        then = now - (delta % interval);
    }

    //Character Collider
    //fillStyle and fillRect do not work here
    //Throws error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined
    map.fillStyle="#CCFFEE";
    map.fillRect(p1Collider.x, p1Collider.y, p1Collider.w, p1Collider.h);
}

update();
draw;
```

Comment: "Global object declared in function"??? You can't _declare_ globals in a function.

Comment: If a variable is declared within a function using `var myVar;` it is local to the function. If it is declared using `myVar;` the lack of the `var` keyword makes it's scope global instead of local to the function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/javascript-is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional

Comment: The lack of `var` makes it an assignment instead of declaration. You can declare only with `var` or `function`, anything else is assignment. It's all about terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the list line is `draw();`.

You are seeing this error because you are calling `update();` and `draw()` **before** `init()` is called and set `map`.

**Solution**: Ensure that `update` and `draw` are called *after* `init` has been called. For example, by placing the calls inside the `load` event handler.

Comment: I just smacked myself in the face. I can't believe I didn't realize this. Thank you so much.