# Javascript: How to run a function after final for loop in previous function is finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I'm writing a Javascript function that pulls words out of a CloudDB database and puts them in one of three arrays: verb, adjective, or noun. Once all the words are in place and the last loop runs, I want to run the next function. Here's the code:

```
function verbnoun(array){
verbs = [];
adjectives = [];
nouns = []; 
for (i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    //console.log(i);  <-- returns 0,1,2,3...57,58 as expected
    my_db.get(array[i], function(err, doc) {

        if (!err){
            if (doc.type == "verb"){

                verbs.push(doc.word);
            }
            else if (doc.type == "adjective"){

                adjectives.push(doc.word);
            }
            else if (doc.type == "noun"){

                nouns.push(doc.word);
            }


        }
        //console.log(i); <-- returns 59,59,59,59,59
        if (i+1 == array.length){
            nextFunction(verbs, adjectives, nouns);
        }       

    });
}
```

}

But I can't figure out how to run the next function after the last loop. If I try to run it outside of the for loop, I just get empty arrays. Using an if statement to trigger on the last loop doesn't seem to work either, because the "i" in the for loop is stuck on 59 each time instead of counting up from 0,1,2,3,etc (see comment in code), so I can't single out which is the last loop.

This is my first post on StackExchange, so thanks for your patience.

Comment: There are multiple issues as Crowder already noted. See this post [Is using 'var' to declare variables optional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are suffering from closure over `i`, which has (probably) been incremented all the way up to 59 before any of the `get` calls return and fire their callback.

Essentially, `i` represents the number of requests *sent*, not the number that have returned successfully. You need a different counter to track that value.

```js
function verbnoun(array) {
  verbs = [];
  adjectives = [];
  nouns = [];
  
  // New counter for completed requests
  var finished = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //console.log(i);  <-- returns 1,2,3...57,58,59 as expected
    my_db.get(array[i], function(err, doc) {

      if (!err) {
        if (doc.type == "verb") {

          verbs.push(doc.word);
        } else if (doc.type == "adjective") {

          adjectives.push(doc.word);
        } else if (doc.type == "noun") {

          nouns.push(doc.word);
        }


      }
      //console.log(i); <-- returns 59,59,59,59,59
      if (++finished == array.length) {
        nextFunction(verbs, adjectives, nouns);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: *"You are suffering from closure over i, which has (probably) been incremented all the way up to 59"* No "probably" about it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I imagine in an unusually-threaded runtime, the callbacks could fire before `i` has gotten all the way to 59.

Comment: @ssube: V8, the engine NodeJS is built on, does not behave that way. It uses a single thread, as most (but not all, true!) JavaScript engines do.

Comment: @PaulBischoff while this should fix your problem, you may want to look at some of the other suggestions T.J.Crowder made in his answer. You have a few other lingering issues.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into two (or possibly three) issues there:

1. The reason you can't do it after the `for` loop is that the `get` calls to the database haven't finished yet; they're asynchronous. In fact, it's important to remember that your function will return **before** the first `get` returns.
2. `i` within the callback you passed `get` is an *enduring reference* to the variable `i`, not a copy of it when the callback was created, which is why you saw it was always 59 (the array length).
3. Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring your local variables.

See comments for how you might address it:

```
function verbnoun(array) {
    // Use var to declare your variables
    var verbs = [];
    var adjectives = [];
    var nouns = [];

    // Use a counter to remember how many responses you've had
    var responses = 0;

    // Schedule the calls
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Call a function do do the work, passing in the index
        // for this loop
        doGet(i);
    }

    // Remember, your function returns at this point, before ANY
    // of the callbacks occurs

    // This function does the work
    function doGet(index) {
        // Because we're using `index`, not `i`, we get a value
        // for each call that won't change
        my_db.get(array[index], function(err, doc) {

            if (!err) {
                if (doc.type == "verb") {
                    verbs.push(doc.word);
                } else if (doc.type == "adjective") {
                    adjectives.push(doc.word);
                } else if (doc.type == "noun") {
                    nouns.push(doc.word);
                }
            }

            // Count this response
            ++responses;

            // If we have all of them, we're done
            if (responses == array.length) {
                nextFunction(verbs, adjectives, nouns);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Although actually, in this particular case, we don't need `index` within the callback, so we didn't absolutely need to separate the calls out into a builder function. But it still makes for a nice, clean separation of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Will try to incorporate better practices regarding local variables in the future.

Comment: @PaulBischoff: No worries. You can force things by adding `"use strict";` at the top of your JS files, which will turn *The Horror of Implicit Globals* into a nice, easy-to-debug `ReferenceError`. :-)