# Variables in a Javascript module visible outside of it?

Tags: javascript, module, scope, global-variables, static-classes

To start, I'm coming from a .NET world, where there are static classes (C#, also known as modules in VB) and instance classes - those you can instantiate.

This question is about Javascript, where I'm trying to recreate the pattern I already know and make a module / static class. Here is the code:

```
var MyModule = {
    variable1: 0,
    variable2: 1,
    method1: function() {
        //code goes here
    },
    method2: function() {
        //mode code goes here
    },
    method3: function() {
        //and some more just to prove the pattern        
    }
}

method1(); //error - no such method - ok, good, I expect that
variable1 = 5; //silently assigns a variable inside MyModule to 5 ?
```

Please explain why methods declared inside a namespace are not visible, but variables are ? Also, is there a way to prevent those variables from being visible outside of `MyModule`, even in the same script ?

Comment: This is not a namespace, nor is it a module. This is a plain JS object. All of the properties are visible. I don't know why you think `method1` throws an error - I don't think it does. Not in the JSFiddle you've provided. `variable1 = 5` assigns a global variable, not the one in the object.

Comment: Here is a (slightly) updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs4y1k19/1/) that shows that the function is indeed accessible. As an aside method is an OO terminology that is not applicable - JavaScript has functions.

Comment: @Vld: Yes, you are right, for some reason `method1` does not throw an error in my JSFiddle. It does, however, throw an error in production code, guess I need to spend more time with it to find out why. Part of the confusion was my expectation to get an error on line `variable1 = 5`, like "non-existing variable, use of undefined variable or similar".

Comment: @Vld: In production code I get Javascript runtime error: 'methodname' is undefined. Which I don't get if I prefix with my module name, it just works normally. I was really hoping to get OO terms working after that.

Comment: if you use the "use strict" directive, then it'd throw an error, in normal mode, it is an implied global and you are actually assigning `window.variable1 = 5`

Comment: As for your production code - then I assume you are calling these from different scopes. A JS object does not do any hiding. Indeed, the module pattern aims to remedy that - check a resource on them like [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) or [Addy Osmani's excellent book](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript)

Comment: @Vld: Thanks for "use strict", I didn't know about it. Although JSFiddle does not support it, unfortunately.

Comment: @Vld: It's the same script file, shouldn't be any different from jsfiddle behavior, but it does work differently. :)

Comment: JSFiddle, does support it but you need to do it in functional scope (using a closure): [example](https://jsfiddle.net/xs4y1k19/2/). As for the visibility issue - JS has only two scopes - function and global. If your `MyModule` is in a function, it's not visible outside. A closure provides a functional scope to anything inside, which can insulate variables from the outside world - they won't go to the global scope (automatically), nor will they be accessible from outside (unless you export them in some fashion).

Comment: @Vld: This closure thing is mind bending for me at this point. Could you provide an example based on my JS in the question to illustrate how I can hide those variables / methods from the outside world ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only point you at the module patterns written by other people way smarter than me. They are how I learned about the module pattern to begin with, so I can guarantee that they are tried and tested. I am writing up an answer in order to flesh it out at the moment, will post shortly.

Comment: @Vld: Thanks. BTW, I updated my question with correct code which shows the error when a method gets called. If I don't prefix it with module name, it fails, regardless of option strict. For JSFiddle you need to use F12 dev console to see the error. I didn't realize my code was wrong in the question and the original fiddle. Sorry about that.

Comment: ah yes - with the updated code, I can see the problem - it's because you call `method1()` but that does not exist, indeed. I will add why to my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will start by trying to address some misconceptions - your module is actually a [plain JavaScript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) initialised using a literal. An object does not hide any information - JavaScript does not have `private` and `public` scope the same way as, say Java does. Furthermore, the only way to access properties of an object is to access them through it

```
method1();
```

This fails because you are trying to get a variable called `method1` and execute it. This does not exist, hence the error. What you *can* do, however, is `MyModule.method1()`. This is because `MyModule` is an actual object. In Java, this would be similar to having `Object MyModule = new Object()`. You can thus call methods on it, like `MyModule.toString()` - the only "unconventional" thing, is that the instance is named with a capital letter - variables in Java and JavaScript normally start with lower case but only by convention - there is no language feature that mandates it.

Next, there is this line:

```
variable1 = 5; //silently assigns a variable inside MyModule to 5 ?
```

To answer the comment on the line - no, it doesn't. The above line is equivalent to doing `window.variable1 = 5`. What you have there is called an "implied global". The name is fairly self descriptive, but just to clarify `window.foo = 42` is an explicit global `foo = 42` is *implied* because it falls back to the `window` object. However, `var foo = 42` is *not* a global - the [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword does not attach to or use the global `window` object. If you use the ["use strict"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) directive you will cause the JavaScript engine to throw an error when it encounters an implied global.

Now, with these misconceptions aside, there is another minor one that I will merely gloss over but it's actually a major thing - `MyModule.method1` and so on are *functions* rather than methods. A method is an Object Oriented terminology for a subroutine that also carries an implied state, which is the object it's assigned to. A function, however, is a free floating executable code that does not intrinsically "belong" to an object. The distinction may seem rather academic, but it has a big impact. However, I'll ask you to trust me on this one, as this is too broad a topic to cover here.

So, that's what's wrong. How do we make it *right*? First, on scopes, as that is needed for the rest of it:

JavaScript has two scopes - global and functional. Here is what this means, exactly:

```
var foo = 42;

function bar(input) {
    var foo = input;
    return foo;
}

console.log(bar(5)); //5
console.log(foo); //42
```

We have too variables called `foo` - one inside a function one not. Assigning one does not change the other - it's because they are in different scopes. That's thanks to the `var` keyword - if that was omitted inside the function, then we would be accessing the same thing

```
var foo = 42;

function bar(input) {
    foo = input;
    return foo;
}

console.log(bar(5)); //5
console.log(foo); //5
```

This is because the inner `foo` is not declared to be in the functional scope, so it accesses the outer (and with no outer - the `window.foo` property).

That's simple enough. However, there is a hidden aspect here that is not immediately obvious yet it bears mentioning: there are *only* two scopes. Here is what I mean

```
function bar(condition) {
    var foo = 5;
    if (condition) {
        var foo = 42;
    }
    return foo;
}

console.log( bar(false) ); //5
console.log( bar(true) ); //42
```

So, even though we seemingly declare a new `foo` property inside the if statement that's actually the same one as the first one. Other languages have a block scope inside `{ }` so, variables declared there, stay there. Not true in JavaScript. Easy to miss, so it's important to note.

Now, onto your problem. There are excellent resources about the JavaScript module pattern, to mention but a few: [Addy Osmani's "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns" book](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) has a very good description, [Todd Motto](https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/) also has, what I believe is, a good article for beginners while [the Adequately Good post](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) goes more in-depth yet it's still accessible. They all cover the Module pattern. You will actually found many Module patterns - in those resources and around the web. What the Module allows you to do is have something similar to `public` and `private` from other languages. I will not try to explain it, since I think other people have done it way better than I can. However, I will just do a very brief explanation what a Module is. Again, other resources can cover this better.

A Module leverages a JavaScript feature called Closure more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) (one of the most upvoted Stack Overflow questions). Remember how I said, there are two scopes in JavaScript? A closure, to put it simply, provides a functional scope. Here is how it looks like:

```
 (function() { /* your code goes here */ })()
```

To dissect this briefly you have a function with your code an that is enclosed in `(/* function goes here */)()`. In effect what this does is that executes the function so everything *inside* is put into functional scope. It is very powerful, however, and here is an example

```
var closure = (function() { 
    var privateVar = "secret";
    return {
       publicVar: 42,
       getPrivateVar() { return privateVar; }
    }
})()

console.log(closure.publicVar); //42
console.log(closure.getPrivateVar()); //"secret"
//let's change this
closure.publicVar = 5;
closure.privateVar = "changed";

console.log(closure.publicVar); //5
console.log(closure.getPrivateVar()); //"secret"
```

And just like that we have (something resembling) a private field. Again, `var privateVar` will stay "bottled up" inside the function scope and would not be accessible outside. Incidentally, this is an example of the Module pattern. Instead of `var closure` I could have called it `myModule`. It is a rather simplistic take on it but, here is the thing - it doesn't get more complicated. All the different Modules boil down to very similar things - you just expose data in different manners. Yet, the concept is similar - the "private" fields stay inside, and the "public" ones, you can access from elsewhere.

This is long, but hopefully should cover the basics you need to get going.

Comment: One small question - if I declare a variable outside of a function, like `var p = 5`, is it equivalent to `p = 5` ? (without strict) Other than that, great answer, much appreciated. I can only give 25 points max, and for sure it deserves more than that. Hopefully others will help me. :) It's nice that you included an example of a public get property with a private backing field - something I did not think was possible in JS.

Comment: @Neolisk - no, if you use `var` the variable doesn't get attached to `window`. This is useful to protect unwanted things added there. One thing I didn't explicitly mention (yet is used) is that a functional scope (and hence a closure) can access anything from OUTSIDE as well as inside. If you look at the second example where `function bar` is, that is a function accessing an outside variable. Thus, you can actually have nested closures, where the inner closure can access variables from the outer one but not the other way around. This sort of works like nested classes from Java.

Comment: Then it seems like there are 3 scopes, not 2. 1. window/global (forgot to use var, or explicitly used window), 2. script (used var outside of a function) and 3. function (used var inside a function). Please confirm.

Comment: No, it's global/functional. Nested functions are still counted as functional. If you remove `var` it doesn't make it "more global". In essence, if you do `foo = 5`, then JS just starts looking through your stacks until it finds one - if its not in the current function, outer function (if any). If it's not in any function, it checks the global scope. If you don't have `var foo` in the global scope, JS still needs to find _something_ so it falls back to `window` and gives you the _property_ called `foo`. In most cases, that doesn't exist, yet it's valid `var a = {}; a.foo = 5;` works the same.

Comment: Actually, to re-word it slightly - if you try to access `foo` and there is no _variable_ called that, you will get the `window` _property_ called `foo`. A variable and `window` can both be in the global scope.

Comment: I think I'm clear now, originally thought that window is global scope. Turns out they two different things. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Yeah, I realise I did not make it exactly clear, sorry. Just to make it clear `window` is in the global scope but is not itself the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

As always before asking a question on Stack Overflow, [I created a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xs4y1k19/4/) for attaching to the question, and several steps later figured what the problem was. This happens often actually. But this time I would like to share my findings with the public. The JS gurus probably already know this, while some less experienced developers may find this information helpful.

[I had two instances of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485439/897326) `variable1`, one belonging to `MyModule` and the other one belonging to `window` (global scope). When I hover over `variable1` in debugger, even though it's inside `MyModule`, the debugger will display a global value. Looks like a bug in Visual Studio 2015, but this is how it works. Then I put a breakpoint in one of the `MyModule`'s functions and noticed it shows a different value if a variable is prefixed with `this`. Obviously, JS syntax does not allow putting `this` during declaration of `MyModule`, so just have to live with how JS debugger works in Visual Studio.

If my explanation makes little sense, try hovering over a variable at the top of any class definition inside a C# project, for example. At any point during debugging, regardless of who declared what, you will see latest and correct values there. The difference of IDE behavior is what caused confusion for me. Also that Javascript has a tendency of creating global variables, if you were not careful enough with variable declaration.