# Multiple Javascript Sketches in P5JS Editor?

Tags: javascript, file, editor, processing

I'm relatively new to P5JS and the P5JS editor. I am also new to Stack Overflow. I am trying to split my code into multiple sketches (.js files) by opening new tabs in the editor, as is explained in this 'Coding Train' video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yk18ZKvXBj4

I believe I followed the steps in the video accurately. My 'index.html' file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <script src="libraries/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="mybutton.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="p5.collide2d.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style> body {padding: 0; margin: 0;} canvas {vertical-align: top;} </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

My goal was to take this function for an object called 'MyButton' in my program:

```
function MyButton(xLoc, yLoc) {
  this.on = false;
  this.startXLoc = xLoc;
  this.startYLoc = yLoc;
  this.xLoc = xLoc;
  this.yLoc = yLoc;
  this.display = function() {
    if (this.on) {
      fill(255);
    } else {
      fill(100, 0, 0);
    }
    rect(this.xLoc, this.yLoc, 30, 30);
  }
}
```

and give it its own file, called 'mybutton.js', to make the normal 'sketch.js' file less cluttered. For now, the 'sketch.js' file looks like this:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();
}

var testButton = new MyButton(50, 50);  //This line produces the error
console.log(testButton);

function draw() {
  background(40);
  testButton.display();
}
```

However, when I run the code this way, I get this error on line 7:

```
7: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

Whereas if I run the code with the 'MyButton' function inside of the 'sketch.js' file (and I don't give it its own file), it runs correctly, and I get no errors at all. I'm not sure what the problem is. How can I give the 'MyButton' function its own file without any errors? If it makes any difference, I am running P5JS on Linux Mint. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What exact line is the error on? Also you might not want to call something node.js as that is something [pretty specific](https://nodejs.org/en/) and might confuse people reading your question. Can you post the full content of your `index.html` file, or better yet post a fiddle or a CodePen running this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `var` from before testButton, then the error is alleviated (like so):

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();

  testButton = new MyButton(50, 50);  //This line produces the error
  console.log(testButton);

}
```

The original issue is that p5js needs the variable declared within setup for it to be accessed in the draw loop. Removing var from the global declaration makes `testButton` very similar to a global variable (but not quite) allowing the draw loop to "see" the variable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485439/5249681) answer for more details.

Comment: Thank you! This explains why it worked in some of my projects and not others - I must have been using "var" sometimes and not other times.