# In Node script, variable defined without 'var' appears to not be in the global scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to reproduce [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)'s answer to [Is using 'var' to declare variables optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional#answer-2485895) with the following (adapted) Node.js script:

```
var foo = "I'm global";
var bar = "So am I";

function myfunc() {
    var foo = "I'm local, the previous 'foo' didn't notice a thing";
    var baz = "I'm local, too";

    function innermyfunc() {
        var foo = "I'm even more local, all three 'foos' have different values";
        baz = "I just changed 'baz' one scope higher, but it's still not global";
        bar = "I just changed the global 'bar' variable";
        xyz = "I just created a new global variable";
    }
}

console.log(xyz)
```

However, this leads to a

```
console.log(xyz)
            ^

ReferenceError: xyz is not defined
```

However, as I understand from his answer this should be `"I just created a new global variable"`, because it was defined without the `var` keyword and therefore 'bubbles up' until it reaches and attached to the global object.

Why is this not the case?

(I also have a second question: in the original answer the function names `myfunc` and `innermyfunc` were not there, but this leads to a `SyntaxError`. Is it not allowed to define anonymous functions in Node?)

Comment: Node.js doesn't use global scope in that way.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Comment: In the code you posted, the functions aren't called. It's helpful with a simple sample like this for people to be able to copy/paste and reproduce your results.

Comment: Implicit globals don't work if you try to use the variable before it's assigned a value.

Comment: You **can** have anonymous functions and use function expressions like `function(){ console.log('hello')` -- you just need to use them like `var Fn = function(){console.log("hello")` or `const Fn = () => console.log("hello")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `xyz` won't be declared until you actually call the functions. Then `xyz` will be in the scope of the file (but not really global) and your `console.log()` should work as expected.

This, for example, will log the string to the console:

```
function myfunc() {

    function innermyfunc() {
        xyz = "I just created a new global variable";
    }
    innermyfunc()
}

myfunc()
console.log(xyz)
```

Having said that, it's a generally-accepted bad practice to declare variable like this. It's much better to use `var xyz` (or `const` or `let`) at the top of the file where you can see them easily and understand they should be scoped to the file. This will save you some bug-hunting time, I promise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the functions

```
function func(){
    a = 5;
}
console.log(a); // a is not defined
func();
console.log(a); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the functions for xyz to be declared. Also this will also throw an error if you are using strict mode.