# Skip declaration in setup? Skip const || let || var in setup? p5.js

Tags: dom, installation, declaration, skip, p5.js

Why I could not declare variable in setup and it still work and fine?

Where I could skip declaration, what is negative part of that skiping? - **Main question**

Here is example of code without declaration and it work fine:

```js
   function setup(){
     canvas = createCanvas(innerWidth, innerHeight);
   }
   function mouseClicked(){
      canvas.style('margin-top', '5px');
   }
```

Here is same code with declaration how should it be:

```js
   let canvas;
   function setup(){
     canvas = createCanvas(innerWidth, innerHeight);
   }
   function mouseClicked(){
      canvas.style('margin-top', '5px');
   }
```

and I have also code in console that shows as it should be and I understand why it is so : [declaration variables in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW97T.jpg)

It is working on any of DOM element (not only canvas)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Yes your explanation helps me thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

This is a JavaScript thing. See here for more info:

- [Is using 'var' to declare variables optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional)
- [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it)

Basically, if you don't use `var` or `let` or `const`, then the variable is put in the global scope. In this case it doesn't really matter, since you're putting the variables in the global scope no matter what.

But it's a good idea to always use `var` or `let` or `const` to declare a variable, even if you don't technically need it.