# Declaring a variable that isn't var, const or let

Tags: javascript

I'm refreshing my JS knowledge by doing a JS course. There's something about variables that have left me a little confused.

```js
var variableVar = 'This is a variable pre ES6'; // var
let variableLet = 'This is a variable that can be changed'; // let
const variableConst = 'This variable cannot be changed'; // con
alsoWorks = 'This also works'; // What's this?

console.log(variableVar);
console.log(variableLet);
console.log(variableConst);
console.log(alsoWorks);
```

I understand var, const and let. I also noticed I don't need to declare any of these for a variable to work e.g. `alsoWorks = 'This also works';`. Why shouldn't I write a variable like this?

Comment: Because it's declaring it in the global scope. Possible dupes of [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when should I use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-should-i-use-it-or-omit-it) and [Is using 'var' to declare variables optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional).

Comment: Open the console and add `alsoWorks = 'This also works';`, then notice that window.alsoWorks was set.  In the context of the browser, the window object is the global scope, and you just modified it.

Comment: You can get rid of this and some other oddities of javascript by putting "use strict"; at the top your script or function.

Comment: Thank you, I'll explore the duplicate questions.