# What's the difference between "for(let item of iter)" and ''for(item of iter)" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iterator

I often uses the "for of" statement to traversal an iterator, just like the following:

```js
for(item of myIterator){
    console.log(item)
}
```

But recently, I found that the offical statement is:

```js
for(let item of myIterator){
    console.log(item)
}
```

And they are both executing right, I wonder if they have any difference. Thx!

Comment: The difference is that `item` is unknown to JavaScript unless you declare it first, so the first example creates a linter warning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is using 'var' to declare variables optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional)

Comment: Without `let`, `item` becomes a global variable (assuming you haven't declared it with `let` or `var` before the for loop)

Answer (score 2):

Let is a scoped variable, so will only work inside it's scope {}.

```
var myIterator = [0,1,2,3]

//non scoped variables works also out of for-loop, check
for(item of myIterator){
    console.log(item)
}

console.log(item)
```

The above example will print all items and when finished, item variable is still the last item of the iteration
Now try again with let scoped variable

```
//scoped variables works only inside for-loop instruction
for(let item2 of myIterator){
    console.log(item2)
}

console.log(item2)
```

Now item2 is no longer avaliable, because is out of scope and the instruction with throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a variable that is not already declared, javascript will declare it in the current function scope or in the global object scope (aka **window** in browser, or **global** in node.js), this is the same behavior when you use the **var** keyword to declare a variable.

So your first "**for of**" will create a variable named item that is accessible outside of **for** scope.

The **let** keyword has block scope, so it's accessible only inside the for loop.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]

for (item of arr) {
    console.log(item)
}

for (let item2 of arr) {
    console.log(item)
}

console.log(item)
console.log(item2)
```

The second console.log will fail with a ReferenceError: item2 is not defined.

Comment: It explains the matter, I really didn't know that a variable can be assigned before declared in JavaScript althrough I have wrote it for two years

Answer (score 0):

Using `let` in this way will let you avoid accidentally creating a closure if you are calling a function in your loop and passing the counter as a parameter.