# Is there an error in this Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

```js
function tipCalculator(bill) {
  var tip;
  if (bill < 50) {
    tip = 0.2 * bill;
  } else if (bill > 50 && bill < 200) {
    tip = 0.15 * bill;
  } else {
    tip = 0.10 * bill;
  }
  return tip;
}

bills = [124, 48, 268];
Tip = [tipCalculator(bills[0]),
  tipCalculator(bills[1]),
  tipCalculator(bills[2])
];

console.log(Tip);
```

I have written this Javascript code pls tell me if this is correct or not because I have not defined the Arrays bills and Tip

Comment: When you don't use a `var` keyword, it makes them global variables, attached to `window`.

Comment: Given the question in title, then No! There is no error in your code.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is using 'var' to declare variables optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485423/is-using-var-to-declare-variables-optional)

Comment: @Guy Incognito - it's definitely not a duplication of that question.

Comment: It's an exact duplicate.

Comment: Is the code not doing what you expected it to? It's a bit unclear

Answer (score 3):

It's valid syntactically, in loose mode.

There's an argument to be made that it has an error, though, because as you say you don't declare `bills` or `tip`, so the code is relying on what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): If you assign to an undeclared identifier in loose mode, it creates a **global** variable. Not a good idea.

I recommend using strict mode, which makes doing that an error:

```js
"use strict";
function tipCalculator(bill) {
  var tip;
  if (bill < 50) {
    tip = 0.2 * bill;
  } else if (bill > 50 && bill < 200) {
    tip = 0.15 * bill;
  } else {
    tip = 0.10 * bill;
  }
  return tip;
}

bills = [124, 48, 268];
Tip = [tipCalculator(bills[0]),
  tipCalculator(bills[1]),
  tipCalculator(bills[2])
];

console.log(Tip);
```

Strict mode is opt-in in scripts (the `"use strict";` above), but is the default within `class` constructs and JavaScript standard modules (aka "ESM modules").